# Kafka: Messages disappearing from topics, largestTime=0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have messages disappearing from topics on Apache Kafka with versions 2.3, 2.4.0, 2.4.1 and 2.5.0. We noticed this when we make a rolling deployment of our clusters and unfortunately it doesn't happen every time, so it's very inconsistent.

Sometimes we lose all messages inside a topic, other times we lose all messages inside a partition. When this happens the following log is a constant:

```
[2020-04-27 10:36:40,386] INFO [Log partition=test-lost-messages-5, dir=/var/kafkadata/data01/data] Deleting segments List(LogSegment(baseOffset=6, size=728, lastModifiedTime=1587978859000, largestTime=0)) (kafka.log.Log)
```

There is also a previous log saying this segment hit the retention time breach of 24 hours. In this example, the message was produced ~12 minutes before the deployment.

Notice, all messages that are wrongly deleted have `largestTime=0` and the ones that are properly deleted have a valid timestamp in there. From what we read from documentation and code it looks like the `largestTime` is used to calculate if a given segment reached the time breach or not.

Since we can observe this in multiple versions of Kafka, we think this might be related to anything external to Kafka. E.g Zookeeper.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this could be happening? We are using Zookeeper 3.6.0.

Answer (score 5):

We found out that the cause was not related to Kafka itself but to the volume where we stored the logs. Still, the following explanation might be useful for educational purposes:

In detail, it was a permission problem where Kafka was not able to read the `.timeindex` files when the log cleaner was triggered. **This caused `largestTime` to be `0` and lead to some messages being deleted way before the retention time.**

Each topic partition is divided into several segments and the last are then stored into different `.log` files that contain the actual messages. For each `.log` file there is a `.timeindex` file containing a map between offset and `lastModifiedTime`.

When Kafka needs to check if a segment is deletable, it searches for the most recent offset `lastModifiedTime` and stores it as largestTime. Then, checks if the retention limit was reached: `currentTime - largestTime > retentionTime`.

If so, it deletes the segment and the respective messages.

Since Kafka was not able to read the file, `largestTime` was `0` and the check `currentTime > retentionTime` was always true for our 1-day retention.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure date is synced between all Kafka brokers and ZooKeeper nodes.
Bash command: `date`.
Compare year, day, hour and minute.